# How a bmp file bytes sorted as little endian, and gives me the first 2 bytes reverse?

Tags: c, readfile, bmp

Everyone knows that BMP files are little-endian. The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) page says that the first 2 bytes must be `0x424D` to make sure that this file is BMP, but when I am getting the first 2 bytes from a BMP file, it gives me the two bytes in reverse `0x4D42`.

**My code:**

```
FILE *file;
unsigned short bmpidentifier;

if((file = fopen("c://loser.bmp", "rb")) == NULL){
   perror("The problem is");
   return -1;
}

fread(&bmpidentifier, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, file);
if(bmpidentifier == 0x424D){
   printf("The file actually is a bmp file.\n");
} else{
   printf("%X\n", bmpidentifier);
   printf("The file is not a bmp file.\n");
}
```

Now, how are the BMP file bytes sorted as little-endian, and giving me the first 2 bytes reversed?

Comment: What architecture are you on? Could it be that you are on something that uses big-endian (and hence switches the order)?

Comment: Check your computer's properties (like which chip it uses).

Comment: I don't know, and installing any software would probably be more work than just finding out whether or not your computer stores stuff in big-endian or little-endian order. It could very well be that the ordering your computer uses accounts for what you see.

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_and_hardware) might help you understand roughly what I'm talking about.

Comment: I still think it's because your computer uses an endianness that you're not expecting. If you read one character at a time, does it do what you expect?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35877/discussion-between-dennis-meng-and-lion-king)

Comment: @DennisMeng: You're on completely the wrong track. OP is using Windows, and aside from some failed experiments like running NT 3.x on the Alpha, Windows is exclusively little-endian.

Comment: @R.. Okay, just wanted to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first byte is 'B' (0x42), the second byte is 'M' (0x4D)

A little endian `uint16_t` would see this as 0x4D42 which is what you are reading.  Try the following instead for a endian independent solution.

```
char BM[3];
BM[2] = '\0';
if (fread(BM, 1, 2, file) && (strcmp("BM",BM)==0)) {
  printf("The file actually is a bmp file.\n");
}
```

---

By the way Wiki says "ID field (42h, 4Dh)", not "first 2 bytes must be 0x424D".

Comment: Do you mean, check if the first bytes is `BM` instead check by using hexadecimal, also how this `0x424D` as ->  `0x4642`.

Comment: @Lion King Yes - for there is some endian confusion here and "BM" is clear.  A next higher level approach would be to instead read the entire 14-byte "Bitmap File Header" into a structure and test it for validity.  But that is another question that may involve packing.

Comment: 0x424D vs. 0x4642  First byte in BMP is 0x42.  0x42 is the least significant portion of uint16_t on a little endian machine.

Comment: I'm still not understand about `0x424D -> 0x4642`.

Comment: Yes, look at this [An Essay on Endian Order](http://people.cs.umass.edu/~verts/cs32/endian.html).

Comment: Again, the first byte is 0x42, the next byte is 0x4D.  When you read that as a `unsigned short` your should expect to receive 0x4D42.  That _is_ what you read.  The idea that you should read 0x424D is incorrect.  You mis-understood the wiki article.

Comment: But I think supposed if `little-Ending` must be read as `0x424D`, but if `big-Ending` must read as `0x4D42`. that what I learned about Endian Order.

Comment: No, you have it backwards: little-Ending reads as 0x4D42, the little (least significant byte 0x42) is in the first memory byte, followed by the most significant byte (0x4D).  GTG now.  I'll delete most of my comments here later after you have reviewed them.

Comment: Ok, Note that when I read a file uses Big-Ending, also, gives me the bytes as reverse `0x4D42`, so the two types gives me the bytes as reverse.

Comment: @LionKing Little endian means the bytes of a multi-byte data type (ex: `int` on most systems is now 32 bits, hence 4 bytes) are stored sequentially from *least* significant byte (the lower 8 bits) to *most* significant byte (the *highest* eight bits). An example would be 2059145780, which in hex is 0x7ABC1234. A little endian system the bytes are stored `0x34 0x12 0xBC 0x7A`. A big-endian storage would be `0x7A 0xBC 0x12 0x34`. (and +1 for this answer, though i'd just check the bytes one by one after reading them into an `unsigned char` array block. `strcmp()` is not needed whatsoever).

Comment: @WhozCraig the `strcmp()` was used to avoid endian issues that the OP is having and to highlight the 'B' 'M' aspect of the file signature.  The authors of .bmp file format evidently were looking for the first byte is a 'B' and 2nd is an 'M'.  Many detection methods are possible including your 2 I/O calls to read 2 bytes.  I prefer a 14-byte structured header call myself.

Comment: @Lion King  When you say "I read a file uses Big-Ending", are you saying your program runs on a big endian machine or that the text file format somehow uses "Big-Ending"?

Comment: @chux Understandable. I prefer manually assembly of my multi-byte values. I've written too many file-processors (compression extractors and assemblers) for, in some cases, up to 8 different platforms, including big and little endian ASCII, EBCDIC, etc. to do it any other way. Everyone has their ways, so long as they work. The case you pointed out, for example, even `'B'` and `'M'` literal testing of the first to bytes won't work on an EBCDIC platform. You literally use the byte values of the ASCII chars. Its the only truly portable way.